# Add Empty row in RDLC report in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable

I have requirement to add a separator in rdlc report if any empty row comes in datatable.
But when report renders, it ignore empty rows and displays only rows which have data in it.
My data table is like below
[image]

but my report does not these empty rows on my web page.
[image]

What extra code should i write so that it can show empty rows in between like in datatable is displaying.

Note:- Instead of adding empty rows in between data, it is adding a new report as shown in the second screenshot (below actual report)

Comment: Such of functionality is called [grouping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251700(v=vs.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Add Group By for your desired expression (here I am using SlNo for my table) and select Add group footer.
[image]

If you want a blank row then you don't need to write any expression for the newly generated row.
[image]

Comment: Is it possible in Visual Studio 2008?